# Advanced jQuery find

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I got following repeating syntax and I want to keep all `<h1>` that is followed by at least one *not hidden* div, but remove the remaining orphaned `<h1>`:

```
<h1>FIRST</h1>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<h1>SECOND</h1>
<div style="display:none"></div>
<div></div>

<h1>THIRD</h1>
<div style="display:none"></div>
<div style="display:none"></div>

<h1>FOURTH</h1>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```

As you can see, sometimes there is a div preceding the `<h1>` that isn't hidden. So in the third block I want to hide the `<h1>`, but not in the second one or any other one.

What I tried is basically searching for a case where an `<h1>` is followed by another `<h1>` while ignoring all the hidden elements in between:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
    if($(this).nextAll().not(':hidden') == $('h1')) { $(this).hide() }
})
```

Unfortunately it won't hide any of the `<h1>` and I just can't figure out why, although I suspect the `:hidden` attribute being the problem. **It should be noted that in my real code the hidden `<div>` is not hidden by 'display:none', but by using jQuerys `.hide()`!**

Hope someone can help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the most clean solution i can think of:

```
$('h1').each(function(){
  if ( $(this).nextUntil('h1').not(':hidden').length == 0 ) $(this).hide();
});​
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/sagivo/sTveD/

Comment: This somehow would remove every h1!

Comment: too many loops for my taste. I found the solution I came up with in collaboration with micadelli best. Thanks for the effort though

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

For every H1, find all elements before next H1, and if them all are hidden, hide this H1

```
$('h1').each(function() {
var elems = $(this).nextUntil('h1');
var elemsHidden = false;
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    if ($(elems[i]).is(':hidden')) {
        elemsHidden = true;
    } else {
        elemsHidden = false;
    }
}

if (elemsHidden) {
    $(this).hide();
}

});​
```

**UPDATE**

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    var elems = $(this).nextUntil('h1');
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
        if (!$(elems[i]).is(':hidden')) {
            return;
        }
    }        
    $(this).hide();

});​
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Mm6Mz/1/

**UPDATE 2**

```
$('h1').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('h1').is(':visible') ? 0 : $(this).hide() ;
});​
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/Mm6Mz/2/

Comment: In my acual code sometimes there are not only 2 `div` after the `h1` but up to 10, so thats propably a bit overkill for all the `next()`.

Comment: Can you clear up what exactly you are looking for @DanSurfrider

Comment: Well it would be overkill to post all my code here, I'll try to put some more variations into the example code. Basically I'm hiding `div` content and as this would result in an orphaned h1, I want to remove it as well...

Comment: Doesnt work either, it removes `h1` if there's at least one hidden, but I want to keep it if theres at least one visible. So I reversed it a bit and now it works! http://jsfiddle.net/te3fT/ Post it as your answer if you like as you pushed me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can just select the hidden `div` then find the prev `h1`.  It reduces your code and keeps it simple

```
$('div:hidden').prev('h1').hide();
```

jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/tkYbh/

Comment: OP didnt want to hide the second H1

Comment: Oh.. Well the first sentence was pretty confusing.  Wants to remove all. but not really removing all?

Comment: Haha sorry for being confusing, didnt know how to explain it differently